# Getting error msg "The name 'RouteConfig' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, routeconfig

Error   CS0103 :The name 'RouteConfig' does not exist in the current context

[image]

Comment: There usually is a RouteConfig file in the App_Start folder which you seem to be missing. May be look into that.

Comment: The error is correct, its exactly that. Some Visual Studio templates create a RouteConfig file for you in the AppStart folder. This is a bad question. You should clarify what you are trying to do and then outline how or where you/something is going wrong. Following this you should ask a specific question. Not just point out an obvious error. I suspect you are following a tutorial to achieve something you don't fully understand yourself